# Listing directory contents

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I'm trying to write a UNIX command using a pipe that will display the number of files in my home directory including hidden files that begin with a '.'

So far i have:

ls -a .* | wc -l  I get a integer returned

Is my command correct?

Comment: your code looks right, but you don't need the `.*`. IF you want to list number of files in subdirectories as well use `ls -Ra1 | wc -l`

Comment: The other poster suggested i use ls -1 | wc -1 however this i think is only partially correct as the 'a' option allows for all files and hidden files. So i think ls -a | wc -l is correct? Right?

Comment: Yup your code does exactly what you need it to do. I was just suggesting that if you need to also count files in subdirectories as well, you can use the `-R` option to read recursively.

Comment: appreciate it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

While being in current directory:

```bsh
ls -1 | wc -l
```

or specify full path:

```bsh
ls -1 /path/to/dir | wc -l
```

-note that key for `ls` is not `l`, it's `1` - that will skip 'hidden' files (those who starts with `.`). If you want to include them, then:

```bsh
ls -1a /path/to/dir | wc -l
```

-but note, that `.` (current directory pointer) and `..` (parent directory pointer) will be included, so probably you'll want to subtract 2 from result number.

Comment: Thanks.. I knew i was close however when using ls -a .* it returned too many results which made me suspicious as it looked wrong.

Comment: I believe the only part that is unecessary is the ".*". If i remove that I get -  ls -a | wc -l  . Correct?

Comment: `.*` points that you want to list _all directories_ inside current one - and that is not what you want to get. So, use either `.` or full path

Answer (score 1):

> Is my command correct?

No.  Upon saying `ls -a .*`, the command would also return files inside a directory beginning with a `.` in addition to returning `.` and `..`

In order to `display the number of files in my home directory including hidden files that begin with a '.'`, say:

```
find $HOME -type f | wc -l
```

If you want to limit it to only the HOME directory, say:

```
find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `find`:

```
find ~ -type f | wc -l
```

or

```
find ~ -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

if you don't want to find recursively.

Answer (score 0):

YA non recursive command with more pipes:

```
ls -la | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -v total | grep -v d | wc -l
```

Best non recursive - as colleagues above, but to avoid warnings, please put maxdepth before type option:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Recursive:

```
find ~ -type f | wc -l
```